# Модальное окно bootstrap в div fixed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста, если модальное окно находиться в `div` блоке с `position: fixed` контент модального окна находиться за `<div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>`.

Как исправить?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".modal").modal("show");
});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="content">
  <button>Open modal</button>
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимости перемещать код модального окна за `div` `fixed` нет.
Просто можно открыть окно в `body` данной командой.

`$('#myModal').appendTo("body").modal('show');`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]